# show random number of elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have a quick question, I have a random function in my code, and I would like that random function to randomize 9 numbers, and depending in the number that returns, that would display the number of happy faces on my html.

My first question is how do I connect the function with my happy faces, and the second is, should I have all nine happy faces on my html, or should I just have one, and generate the others (depending on the random number) dynamically. right now I have a display: none on the css, I just commented out so you guys could see it.

I added some of the code here

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(init);

var globalNum;

function init(){
 $('.number').click(clickNum);
 console.log('hello from jQuery!');
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}


console.log(getRandomInt(1,9));

function clickNum(){
 var num = $(this).text();
 console.log(num)
 // addNumToDisplay(num);

}

// function displayNum(num){
//  globalNum = 
//  var currentNumber = $('.number').text(num);
//  console.log(currentNumber);
// }
```

```css
* {
 /*outline: 2px solid red;*/
}

p {
 padding: 50%;
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 background: #dbdfe5;
}

body {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.col-sm-8 {
 width: 80%;
 height: 200px;
}

.jumbotron {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
}

.fa-smile-o {
 background-color: yellow;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: .9em;
    width: .9em;
    /*display: none;*/
}

.btn-group {
 position: relative;
 left: 40%;
}

.numbers {
 margin-top: 15px;
 width: 900px;
}

.number {
 font-size: 40px;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
}

#right {
 position: relative;
 height: 80px;
 width: 120px;
 font-size: 30px;
 background-color: lime;
 color: white;
}

.rightButton {
 margin-left: 50px;
 position: absolute;
}

#result {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 padding: 30px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Game 5</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron firstBlock">
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Restart</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Reroll</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Check</button>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron numbers">
   <button class="number">1</button>
   <button class="number">2</button>
   <button class="number">3</button>
   <button class="number">4</button>
   <button class="number">5</button>
   <button class="number">6</button>
   <button class="number">7</button>
   <button class="number">8</button>
   <button class="number">9</button>
   <span class="right">
    <span id="result">5</span>
    <span class="rightButton">
    <button id="right">Right!</button>
    </span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to generate those smiles:

```
$(function() {
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var faces = '',
            i = 0,
            random = getRandomInt(1,9);
        var $firstBlock = $('div.firstBlock').html('');
        for(i;i<=random;i++) {
            faces += '<i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>';
        }
        $firstBlock.append(faces);
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/b3da/gehbLtpa/1/)

Comment: You should re-evaluate `for(i;i<=getRandomInt(1,9);i++)` that has endless loop written all over it ;)

Comment: Thanks b3da, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Lucky500 you should not call a function inside the condition of a for loop like this. Get the value first, then use the value

Answer (score 1):

You connect your code to the DOM using [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/) just like you do already with `$('.number').click(clickNum);`

I would go the dynamic route myself as it is more versatile IMHO

This would work, and here is a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/5mof7ud9/):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.reroll').click(function() {
    addNumToDisplay(getRandomInt(1, 9));    
  });
  $('.number').click(function() {
    addNumToDisplay($(this).text());
  });
});

var globalNum;

function addNumToDisplay(num) {
  $('.firstBlock .fa-smile-o').remove();
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    $('.firstBlock').append('<i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>');
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

```css
* {
  /*outline: 2px solid red;*/
}

p {
  padding: 50%;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #dbdfe5;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.col-sm-8 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
}

.jumbotron {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}

.fa-smile-o {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: .9em;
  width: .9em;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
}

.numbers {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron firstBlock">
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-4x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary restart">Restart</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning reroll">Reroll</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success check">Check</button>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron numbers">
    <button class="number">1</button>
    <button class="number">2</button>
    <button class="number">3</button>
    <button class="number">4</button>
    <button class="number">5</button>
    <button class="number">6</button>
    <button class="number">7</button>
    <button class="number">8</button>
    <button class="number">9</button>
    <span class="right">
    <span id="result">5</span>
    <span class="rightButton">
    <button id="right">Right!</button>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```